# querying rdf/xml in Python

Tags: python, xml, rdf, sparql

The following code:

```
import rdflib.graph as g
graph = g.Graph()
graph.parse('C:\\Python27\\phyton projects\\senticnet-3.0\\senticnet3.rdf.xml', format='xml')
print graph.serialize(format='pretty-xml')
```

returns this data in Python:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:ns1="http://sentic.net/"
  xmlns:ns2="http://sentic.net/api/"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
>
 <ns1:apisemantics>
      <ns2:concept rdf:about="http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/love">
        <ns1:apipolarity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">0.667</ns1:apipolarity>
        <ns1:apiattention rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">0</ns1:apiattention>
        <ns1:apipleasantness rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">1</ns1:apipleasantness>
        <ns1:apiaptitude rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">1</ns1:apiaptitude>
        <ns1:apisemantics rdf:resource="http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/love_another_person"/>
        <ns1:apisemantics rdf:resource="http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/beloved"/>
        <ns1:apisemantics rdf:resource="http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/lust"/>
        <ns1:apisemantics rdf:resource="http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/show_empathy"/>
        <ns1:apisemantics rdf:resource="http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/sexuality"/>
        <ns1:apisensitivity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">0</ns1:apisensitivity>
        <ns1:apitext>love</ns1:apitext>
      </ns2:concept>
    </ns1:apisemantics>
```

How can I query the various elements of this output?

For example, how can i retrieve the value of `apipolarity`?

OR, how can i retrieve all the `apisemantics`e.g. "love_another_person", "beloved"...?

**EDIT**

I am able to retrieve data as follows:

```
qres = result.query(
    """SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
        WHERE {
           ?subject ?predicate ?object.
        }""")

for r in qres.result:
    print str(r[0]), str(r[1]), str(r[2])
```

which returns:

```
http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/a_lot_of_study http://sentic.net/apitext a lot of study
http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/a_lot_of_study http://sentic.net/apiaptitude -0.111
http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/a_lot_of_study http://sentic.net/apiattention -0.005
http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/a_lot_of_study http://sentic.net/apipolarity -0.064
http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/a_lot_of_study http://sentic.net/apipleasantness -0.074
```

How can I now narrow down my query to a specific concept and say, its polarity?

Comment: How about [using a SPARQL query](http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro_to_sparql.html)?  Or the [graph API](http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro_to_graphs.html)?  If those aren't enough, then you'll need to provide much more information about why those aren't working for you.

Comment: I've added the [tag:sparql] here since you found an answer using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example query to retrieve the polarity of concept "*a_little*":

```
qres = result.query(
     """SELECT ?object
       WHERE {
          ?subject ?predicate ?object
          FILTER (?subject = <http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/a_little>)
          FILTER (?predicate = <http://sentic.net/apipolarity>)
        }""")

for r in qres.result:
    print str(r[0])
```

**EDIT**

improved solution as per Joshua's suggestion:

```
qres = result.query(
         """
         prefix concept: <http://sentic.net/api/en/concept/>
         prefix api: <http://sentic.net/api/>
         SELECT ?polarity
           WHERE { 
              concept:%s api:polarity ?polarity
            }
         """%concept) #concept is passed through as a function parameter
    for r in qres.result:
        return str(r[0])
```

Comment: Don't use `filter ( ?subject = ... )`, though.  Just put the URI there.  E.g., `select ?polarity where { <…/a_little> <…/apipolarity> ?polarity }`.

Comment: And good turn around on this.  It's very encouraging to see someone get a reference to a new tool or language, and to see them find a solution using it.  If you're going to be using much SPARQL in the future, there are plenty of [tag:SPARQL] questions and answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can also use some prefixes to make the query a bit cleaner.  Here's a cleaned up version that should return the same results: http://pastebin.com/J5V27HDx.

Comment: Glad to help!  If you end up using the cleaned version of the query (or some variant of it), feel free to edit it into your answer.  And don't forget to accept your answer (when you're allowed to;  I recall that there's some time limit).